# Implement locking & unlocking a document while editing

Tags: javascript, ajax, locking, onunload

Here's the situation:

I have a web-based ticket application, multiple users.

One problem that might occur (and *does* happen in the old version I'm replacing) is that user1 opens a ticket, edits it, and saves it. But while he was editing it, user2 also opened and saved the ticked. The changes user2 made will be lost/overwritten by user1.

To prevent this I implemented a locking mechanism, it's fairly simply:

1. On opening a ticket the PHP script checks for existing locks.
2. If it doesn't find any, it locks & opens the document.
3. In JS, `setTimeout()` and an XmlHttpRequest call to unlocks the ticket after 10 minutes (works w/o problems).
4. **I also set an `unload` event to unlock the ticket when closing/moving away from the window/tab**

The problem sits in step 4: The `unload` event (& it's friend `beforeunload`) just doesn't work well enough to implement this **reliably** (for this feature to have any serious meaning, it needs to be reliable), many browsers don't always fire it when I would like it to be fired (Like pressing back button, hitting F5, closing tab, etc. This varies per browser)

The only alternative I can come up with is using a `setTimeout()` and `XmlHttpRequest()` call to a php script to tell it the page is still open. If this "heartbeat" monitor fails we assume the user moved away from the ticket and unlock the document.

This seems horribly inefficient to me and quickly leads to many requests to the server with even a few users.

Anyone got a better idea on how to handle this?

It needs to work in IE8+ and other modern browsers (ideally, Firefox, Webkit, Opera). I don't care about IE6/IE7, our organization doesn't use those).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using heartbeat pings via XHR is the way to go. Depending on the use case you might also want to send them after the user stopped typing in a field instead of every x seconds - this would ensure the page being kept open but inactive would not keep it locked.

If you send those XHRs after the user stopped typing, use one of the `keydown/up/press` events and a *debounce* / *throttle* script to send the request only when the user stops typing for e.g. 5 seconds and one every x seconds (in case it's likely enough the user will be typing for a long time).

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this and it's already worked much better than unload so far.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it's worth looking into it : **websockets**.
You could establish a connection with the server at page load and when the connection fails (ie the client does not respond to the ping), you can unlock the ticket.
Using something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/#browser-support) ensures you that this procedure will work even on ie8.

- The main **advantage** is that you do not send a request every *n* seconds, but the server sends you a ping every *n* seconds and you don't have to care about `unload/beforeunload` events.  If the client doesn't respond to the ping, unlock the ticket.
- The main **disadvantage** is that you need a server to handle all your websocket connections, which can be done in almost any server-side language, but it can be a bit harder than a simple web-service (in case of xhr polling)

Comment: I (briefly) thought about that. Two problems: Only supported by very recent browsers (and not IE8 or even IE9, this is a requirement), and it's very new technology and and not well tested or understood (HTML/Javascript/Web history teaches us a few things about that. Especially security-wise).

Comment: Security-wise, you're right, it must certainly have security gaps, but from the compatibility point of view, as I said in the post, you can use socket.io. I used it in a project and it uses several fallbacks mechanisms in order to maintain the same api and functionality for browsers that do not have websockets support.

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely missed that it worked on IE8 and was turned off by their unreadable webpage :o

Comment: I could *just* get over that it required an extra server, but there are no fedora packages for node.js :-( And since everything will have to be maintained by someone who is not me doing a manual install doesn't seem wise ... It's an interesting project though.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing ajax heartbeats or unload handlers to unlock the document automatically is tricky.

You problem is that even if you have support for beforeunload in all browsers that you target, it still might not be called if the browser crashes or the user falls asleep.

Look at how webdav works. You explicitly aquire a lock before you start edit, then you save and release the lock explicitly.
Other users can see who has acquired a lock and admins can release locks that has been left behind by accident.